# Remove Blank Items in Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays, post

I have a textarea box that takes barcodes separated by a new line. When they are processed, the new lines become commas. But if somebody inputs:

```
123456


234567
...
```

with a bunch of spaces under each code as such, it then becomes

```
$barcode_list = 123456,,,234567
```

I am able to strip the commas from the end, and I have tried:

```
$array = explode(",", $barcode_list);
foreach($array as $item){ //Separate each item
    if ($item == "") {
        unset($item);
    }
```

but it doens't seem to work, I still get mysqli errors etc. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: How do the newlines become commas?  That seems a good place to fix it.

Comment: What are the mysql errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first remove unnecessary commas, then explode. Fewer steps...

```
// every sequence of commas becomes one comma 
$barcode_list=preg_replace("/,+/",",",$barcode_list);
// explode the string into an array
$array = explode(",", $barcode_list);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing an `unset` that doesn't really affect your `array`.

Do this:

```
$array = explode(",", $barcode_list);
foreach($array as $key => $item){ //Separate each item
    if ($item == "") {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
```